# How can I write subscripts for partial derivative?

Tags: keyboard

I am trying to solve partial derivatives on Mathematica cloud.
I checked the tutorial provided by Wolfram.
And it says I can input differentiation variable by ctrl + _.
However, whenever I am trying this chrome shortcut is working and just pressing control is not giving me any reaction.
Is is a problem of my browser?

It is my first attempt to use mathematica and I think I might miss something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the majority of mathematica code is written in the standalone workspace, which is not browser based. The syntax you describe works very well when using a standard notebook, but in a browser, that particular key combination is already configured for the brower. This is the same for Firefox as well.

[image]

### General advice in mathematica

Generally speaking, the subscript notation is **just visual** in nature.
You could always use the non-subscript variant for taking a partial derivative:

```
D[x^2,x]
```

I would say that subscript notation can be a bit tricky at times as it complicates notation overall. IF you can get away without subscripts, I would suggest you avoid them as an initial step. As you get more confident in mathematica, they will naturally come into your coding practice. :)

### An alternative suggestion

Perhaps you could consider downloading the program itself? If you have a licence through your institution or someplace else, then I would generally recommend that you use the desktop version.

Best,

A.